# how to combine two nodes into one group in Xpath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have html like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="a">10</div>
    <div class="b">11</div>
    <div class="a">20</div>
    <div class="b">21</div>

</div>
```

Sometimes I use `//div[@class="a" or @class="b"]` to get four groups: `[10, 11, 20, 21]`.

But this time I want to get something like this, two groups: `["10 11", "20 21"]`, could I?

I mean that how to combine two nodes(class a, class b) into one group?

Comment: You get what you describe to want. What's the problem ?

Comment: Use //div[@class="a" or @class="b"] I get four groups,  but I want to get two group that each group contains class a, class b, like this, group 1: "10 11", group 2: "20 21"

Comment: Using XPath only, or is XSLT an option, as well?

Comment: I can only use XPath and CSS Selector in that project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a working XPath 2.0 solution ([running example](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22a%22%3E10%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22b%22%3E11%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22a%22%3E20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22b%22%3E21%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22a%22%5D%2Fconcat(%0A%20%20%20%20text()%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%27%20%27%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20string-join((following-sibling%3A%3Adiv%5B%40class%3D%22b%22%5D%2Ftext())%5B1%5D%2C%20%27%27)%0A)%0A&=&input-format=xml&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Standard%20XQuery&dot-notation=off&extract-kind=auto&no-extended-strings=true&no-json=true&no-json-literals=true&only-json-objects=true&strict-type-checking=true&strict-namespaces=true&case-sensitive=true)):

```
//div[@class="a"]/concat(
    text(), 
    ' ', 
    string-join((following-sibling::div[@class="b"]/text())[1], '')
)
```

I don't think a solution with XPath 1.0 would be possible here.

Answer (score 2):

XPath 1.0 has only four data types: node-set, string, number, and boolean. Your desired result is not an instance of one of these types, so it follows that no XPath 1.0 can return it. However, XPath 2.0 allows sequences of strings so as @LukasEder points out, it can be done with 2.0